# Storing multiple tags in one column

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

As it stands, I am trying to build a database that stores details related to a file, such as author, create date and most importantly, tags.

I'm not sure how to go about storing multiple tags for one file, the simplest way i can think of is to store them all as one string of hyperlinks. But this raises the issue of being able to display the tags as links in a windows application in a list view and also how would i be able to filter search results using this method.

A more complex idea i have would be to create a separate table of tags, assign each tag a unique 3 digit integer that would be stored as a combined longer int for multiple tags.

e.g.

```
001 - tag1
002 - tag2
003 - tag3
```

and then store them in the file details as `001002003` if all three tags were related to the file.

If i do it this way, would i have to declare each mod as an object of the class "Mod" in my application and then reassign a hyperlink to each tag value and store the tags as a collection of Tag objects as a property of each mod? Is this a feesable idea or have i over-complicated it somewhat?

EDIT:

Still in the early stages of development, have yet to test out an implementation of it yet but currently im looking at about 50-100 tags.

How would i go about structuring a files_to_tags table? I'm fairly new to relational database modeling, i'd be better at using a CSV to store data but that's not really efficient!

Comment: Since you're coding tags in some way, I assume that you have a predefined set of all possible tags? If that's the case, how many tags is that?

Comment: And why not storing them in a files_to_tags table?.

Comment: Create one table to store all the tags, with each tag having a unique id.  Create another table that will create one record for each combination of file and tag, using the file id and the tag id.  That way you can get all the files for one or more tags, or all the tags for one file.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good case for a bridge table.  Let's say you have in your database:

```
file_info
---------
file_id
author
create_date

tag_info
--------
tag_id
tag_name
```

`tag_id` is a surrogate key, and would be a unique, incrementing value for each new tag.  So it may look like:

```
tag_id  tag_name
------  --------
     1  Apples
     2  Pears
     3  Peaches
```

You then create the bridge, which links files to the applicable tags:

```
file_tag_bridge
---------------
file_id
tag_id
```

The combination of file_id/tag_id will be unique in the table (it is a **compound key**), but a given file_id may be associated with multiple (different) tag_id, and vice-versa.

You will have one row in this table for each tag associated with a file:

```
file_id   tag_id
-------   ------
      1        1
      2        2
      2        3
```

In this case, file 1 is associated with the `Apples` tag; file 2 is associated with `Pears` and `Peaches`.  File 3 is not associated with any tags, and therefore is not represented in the bridge table.